# Strange ripple effect both rounded and square

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, material-design, android-dialogfragment

I was trying to add a `Round Ripple Effect` on a `FragmentDialog` but I end up with this:

[image: Ripple round and square]

**The effect is now Round AND square!**

To add the round effect, I used:

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

The strangest thing is that, after facing this problem, I created another project just to check what could be wrong and, somehow, the problem didn't appear on the other project.

All I can say is that both the xml (layout) and the Java Class (DialogFragment) on both projects are exactly the same!

Any ideia what might be happening?

Comment: try (android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless") -- but not sure if it will fix the issue -- add the xml markup in your Q anyaway

Comment: @LeonardoSibela best way to debug this is : take the XML dump of this via UIAutomator then analyze what is view hierarchy, touch area.

Comment: @Tasos I tried putting the foreground, but it didn't work, but I appreciate your help veru much :)

Comment: @dex I didn't knew about the UIAutomator, but I like this new feature a lot :) Thanks very much for your help. I found out what the problem was by going to every file on both projects and I'll post a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference between the two projects in the `build.gradle (app module)` files.

What I was using:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

I fixed it using:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```